# Arduino Uno 2 I2C devices problem

Tags: i2c

I have two I2C devices connected to an Arduino Uno: an RTC and an OBD interface (see links below). The SCL/SDA of both devices connect parallel to SCL/SDA (respectively) of the Uno. My problem: when I set the time on the RTC (either using the autoset option, or explicitly) it reports back odd readings, like the date set back by 4 days, the hour set back by 2 hours etc. This happens even with the default bare-bones RTC sample sketch.

I tried two RTCs (one DS1307, and the one linked below): both show the same strange behavior. I tried 2 configurations: 1) NO pull-up resistors on either device, 2) two 10K pull-up resistors on BOTH devices. Both situations produce RTC errors. If I detach the OBD sensor from SCL/SDA, the RTC shows the proper time. If I remove the RTC, the OBD by itself (works fine. Before I spend more time experimenting: any advice how to solve this pull-up resistor situation (if this is what it is)?

[Adafruit DS3231 Precision RTC](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3013)

[OBD Freematics interface](https://freematics.com/pages/products/arduino-obd-adapter/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I imagine you are using the [Adafruit Library](https://github.com/adafruit/RTClib), since thats the URL of the product you posted.

If so, in RTClib.h:

```
#define DS1307_ADDRESS  0x68
#define DS3231_ADDRESS  0x68
```

And in the OBDs product page:

```
OBD I2C Address: 0x68

MEMS I2C Address: 0x62
```

Which obviously causes a conflict.

It seems that they have a fixed I2C address (some devices are configurable via software, others with external pins). So the solution would be to use other RTC, other OBD (or change its address) or use a bus splitter, or use a MCU with more than one I2C bus.

Comment: Thanks, well spotted, I'll research this. Why don't they make I2C devices with a small, on-board, solderable jumper to quickly set the address to something else than the default? Rhetorical question...

Comment: Well, they do, it is just not all of them that have this feature :)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the same problem: turns out Adafruit has a multiplexer just for this purpose. Also, there's LTC4316 which (supposedly) converts I2C addresses on the fly.

[Adafruit TCA9548A I2C multiplexer](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2717)

[LTC4316](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/4316fa.pdf)